# Remove or change cloudflare script at top of page

Tags: cloudflare

I am using cloudflare and it is enhancing my website performance, but rocketscript is adding script at the top of page and I think

```
 it  is hurting my SEO

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:1417339881,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok2v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"d1860f61ecdb8c5c3826b01316cc8742",petok:"1fe291a32e5813fc73d592d28d6e79cdc75592ce-1417361255-1800",zone:"altibbi.com",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok2v=919620257c/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]></script>
<script type="text/rocketscript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VQQPU1NSGwcDVVhRAAY="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o?o:e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_requ........
```

How to remove it ? And why it is adding it ?

Comment: False statements are false.

Answer (score 6):

This message is for the people jumping this old thread to get rid of CDATA code from the site.
Just go inside the Page Rules.

Create a rule for your site : http://< mysite >/*

Then add the following :

- Disable Apps
- Smart Errors Off
- Rocket Loader Off

Under free account you can create 3 pages rules. Pretty much enough for doing stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

The Rocket Loader script wouldn't really impact SEO at all. Why do you believe it is? You can always turn that feature off in your performance settings.

Comment: I think they were more asking about CloudFlare improving SEO in general, CloudFlare does do this by improving page load time; we at Creare Group have found this in our data since we joined as a CloudFlare Optimised Partner.